# Group into json array

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgres 9.5

For each `app`, I am trying to count how many `conversations` was started from various urls valued by the `started_at_url` column

I've been able to get a result like this

```
id: 1, ..., data: {"urls" : ["/","/insights","/signin"], "counts" : [1,2,2]}
```

But it would rather have an array of JSON objects of form `{url, count}` instead

My query so far:

```
select
    dt.id as app_id,
    json_build_object(
        'urls', array_agg(dt.started_at_url),
        'counts', array_agg(dt.count)
    ) as data
from (
    select a.id, c.started_at_url, count(c.id) 
    from apps a
    left join conversations c on c.app_id = a.id
    where started_at_url is not null and c.started_at::date > (current_date - (7  || ' days')::interval)::date
    group by a.id, c.started_at_url
) as dt
group by dt.id
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use

```
array_agg(
   json_build_object(
      'url', dt.started_at_url,
      'count', dt.count
   )
)
```

instead of

```
json_build_object(
   'urls', array_agg(dt.started_at_url),
   'counts', array_agg(dt.count)
)
```